# If statement on segment eq url_title - strange behavior

Tags: segments, url-title, ifelse

My goal was to mark current/active article on the list. Code looks like:

```
<ul class="list-plain">
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{segment_3_category_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc" status="open" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}
{if switchee_no_results}<div class=""><p>No entries yet.</p></div>{/if}
<li {if segment_4=="{url_title}"} class="current"{/if}><a href="{site_url}{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>        
{/exp:channel:entries}        
</ul>
```

but no class added to the proper list item.

Then I have decided to check if IF statement works and did simple test run

```
Seg: {segment_4} - URL: {url_title}
{if segment_4=="{url_title}"}FOUND!{/if}
```

no result found even there was proper Seg to Url match.

Then I have checked if there is no results

```
Seg: {segment_4} - URL: {url_title}
{if segment_4=="{url_title}"}FOUND!{if:else}NOT FOUND{/if}
```

and I have got proper matches.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: In the selection of the channel:entries you are selecting products by category of segment 3. In the check you are comparing category on segment 4. Is that correct?

Comment: OP code updated with proper tag - it was some of my tests to get it to work. To be clear - I'm selecting product lists based on category from segment 3 and segment 4 is a product url_title

Comment: Maybe you need to use this? `{if "{segment_4}"=="{url_title}"}`? So putting the `segment_4` between quotes.

Comment: Well, strange but that works. You can post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two variables where you compare one with quotes `""` and one without. So that probably gives a mismatch because it compares the two variables as different types.

So change this:

```
{if segment_4=="{url_title}"} class="current"{/if}
```

into:

```
{if "{segment_4}"=="{url_title}"} class="current"{/if}
```

probably also this would work (not tested).

```
{if {segment_4}=={url_title}} class="current"{/if}
```